# A script with a variable that references a sym links, but I need to move/rename the source file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

we are trying to design a windows command line script that will move and rename a source file when the script is triggered by an application at the end of a transcode job.

The first part of the script is to move the source file:

```
MOVE /Y %1 Z:\Target-Directory
```

the `%1` variable references the source file in a watch folder.
the %source% info for the variable is provided by the host application (Carbon Coder).

the problem - these watch folders only contain a sym link, not the full file. the full source files live on another volume.

So, as you might guess, what happens is that when the script executes, it moves the symlink and not the actual source.

Changing the watch folders to the volume where the actual source files are located is NOT an option. Neither is copying the source files to the current location of the watch folders. The only option we have is to create a sym link in the watch folder that points back to the source media.

with that in mind, is there any way to design a script that will use the variable and know to move the actual source file, not the sym link?

thanks.

---

EDIT:

it looks like the `dir` command does not yield source location info for these files.

```
 Volume in drive K is CarbonCoder-Local
 Volume Serial Number is B0A3-97E8

 Directory of K:\CarbonCoder_WatchFolders\ProResHQ_4Chan_NTSC

03/12/2013  09:56 AM    <DIR>          .
03/12/2013  09:56 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/12/2013  09:56 AM               853 test-01.mov.lnk
03/12/2013  09:56 AM               853 test-02.mov.lnk
03/12/2013  09:56 AM               853 test-03.mov.lnk
03/12/2013  09:56 AM               853 test-04.mov.lnk
03/12/2013  09:56 AM               853 test-05.mov.lnk
               5 File(s)          4,265 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  9,365,513,400,320 bytes free
```

I was mistaken, these are not symlink, but just mircosoft shortcut files.

Comment: Please give an example for the contents of the `%source%` variable.

Comment: example source: K:\CarbonCoder_WatchFolders\ProResHQ_EM_PAL_HD_16Chan\042281_SeriesName_EpisodeName_Standard_Format_Version.mov

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

For batch, use the `dir` command to identify symlinks and their targets.

### Example

```
C:\>mklink symlink.txt C:\Folder\File.txt
symbolic link created for symlink.txt <<===>> C:\Folder\File.txt

C:\>dir Folder
 Volume in drive C is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is DC11-1111

 Directory of C:\

03/11/2013  04:45 PM    <DIR>          .
03/11/2013  04:45 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/11/2013  04:45 PM    <DIR>          Folder
03/11/2013  04:45 PM    <SYMLINK>      symlink.txt [C:\Folder\File.txt]
...
```

### Usage

Edited to add this illustration (untested example) on how to use the `dir` command information as needed in a batch script.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir "%~1" ^| find /i "%~nx1"') do (
    set "Information=%%A"
    for /f "tokens=4*" %%B in ("!Information:%~nx1=!") do (
        echo %%B
    )
)
endlocal
```

#### Output

```
[C:\Folder\File.txt]
```

Comment: Sorry, But I dont understand how that helps. The source files are constantly changing, always different. I can't per-define what they will be?

Comment: @NatGeo - No pre-defining needed.  Use the `dir` command as needed in the batch script.  1. Use the `dir` command on the watch folder to discover the real source file location (`[C:\Folder\File.txt]`) from the symlink (`symlink.txt`).  2. Parse this information for consumption.  3. Use the real source file location for the `move` and `rename` commands.

Comment: sorry, i was wrong, they are not symlinks, but Microsoft shortcut files. when i tested out the dir command it just shows 'test.mov.lnk' - it doesnt list the source location.